# when i activate my plugin i want to auto create pages with shortcodes

Tags: plugin-development

when i activate my plugin i want to auto create pages with shortcodes

this is how my plugin file is structured 
wp-content\plugins\My First Plugin\shortcode\user-activitys.php this is where the relevant html and php for those pages that are need to be created when i activate my plugin

what do i need to include in the user-activitys.php file with my page html and php

and what do i need to include in the main plugin file

to get user-activitys.php page to appear in the page section of wordpress with a shortcode and my html and php appear when i view the frontend page when i activate my plugin

and the code for the main plugin file here

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: our plugin
Description: ....
Author: ...
Version: ...
*/
add_action('admin_menu', 'our_setup_menu');

function our_setup_menu(){
        add_menu_page( 'our Plugin Page', 'our Plugin', 'manage_options', 'our-plugin', 'Admin_Setting_overview', 'our_init' );
}


?>
```

Comment: and the code for the main plugin file here <?php
/*
Plugin Name: our plugin
Description: ....
Author: ...
Version: ...
*/
add_action('admin_menu', 'our_setup_menu');
 
function our_setup_menu(){
        add_menu_page( 'our Plugin Page', 'our Plugin', 'manage_options', 'our-plugin', 'Admin_Setting_overview', 'our_init' );
}
 

 
?>

Comment: Please edit your original comment and add the code there; it's easier to read and will increase your chances of getting help.

Comment: i have added the code in the original comment but its not showing up so i added it to the comments

Answer (score 1):

From what I understood from your question, you will need to use `register_activation_hook()`, which runs when your plugin is activated.

```
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'your_function_name');
```

then in that function you can use `wp_insert_post' to create your page.

Refer this link to pass new post parameters as per your need: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/

Edit:

In your plugin file make a function for shortcode.

```
function function_for_shortcode(){
//Your html here
}
add_shortcode('your_shortcode','function_for_shortcode');
```

Now when you run `register_activation_hook`, provide to `wp_insert_post`, `post_content` as `[your_shortcode]`.

Comment: sort of i need when the plugin activates it creates a new page by shortcode within that page is the shortcode and when viewing the frontend page displays the html within the php file in wp-content\plugins\My First Plugin\shortcode\user-activitys.php  i see i can add this line of code to the top of the file add_shortcode('user-activitys.', 'user-activitys.' );but i dont know what to put in the main plugin file to get that shortcode to creates that new page when i activate my plugin

Comment: I'm still not sure what you want. Anyhow, you can assign `page-template` to new page as your `user-activitys.php`. Or if you absolutely need shortcode, you'll have to put your html in a function and make that function a shortcode.

Comment: thats what i want to do  i do need shortcode, i want to put my html in a function and make that function a shortcode. how do i do it ?

Comment: Edited the answer.